# question on torus grid graph isomorphisms

Tags: graph-theory

Is it true for torus grid graphs that $C_a \square C_{b} \cong C_d \square C_e$ implies $\{a, b\}=\{d, e\}$?

Comment: Handwavy idea: If $4\notin\{a,b\}$, then the only $4$-cycles in $C_a\square C_b$ are the "grid squares", so we can recover $\{a,b\}$ from the graph structure. On the other hand, if $4\in\{a,b\}$ and $4\in\{d,e\}$ then clearly $\{a,b\}=\{d,e\}$, because $C_a\square C_b\cong C_d\square C_e$ implies $ab=de$.

Answer (score 2):

Compute distances from a vertex by a BFS until:

- a non visited vertex is visited by two non adjacent vertices sharing no other common neighbor, then its distance from the starting vertex is $\frac{\min(a, b)}{2}$.
- you visit a vertex already visited and situated at the same distance from the one you came, then its distance from the starting vertex is $\frac{\min(a, b)-1}{2}$.

Using the fact that $n=ab$, you can retrieve the dimensions of your grid.